# JavaScript / Angular RegEx allow only alpahnumeric on paste

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

what i want to do is when the user pastes a big string i want to extract the alphanumeric value from the entered text.

I am doing this in plain JavaScript but angular answers are appreciated.

So far i have the following:

```
document.getElementById("paste").addEventListener("keyup",function(){
var inText= "Thank you for contacting us your code is abd123XYZ we will help you shortly ";

 reg = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
 var wordsArray=inText.split(" ");

 wordsArray.forEach(function(element){
   //   what to do here to only get abd123XYZ 
 });//foreach

});//keyup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var reg = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;
angular.forEach(inText.split(" "),function(d){
         if(reg.test(d))
         {
            console.log(d);
         }
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/1hUrLUspzMjQobkOuFwy?p=info)

Comment: @krv - did you try this solution ? I edit my answer.

Comment: @gauravbhavsar thanks was exactly the solution i was looking for..It pulls out all the words with alphanumeric values so we can choose what we want..

Comment: is there any way i can make this to accept both alphanumeric or numeric..currently it only get alphanumeric ?

Comment: Yes, `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` this means at least one alphabet, so remove `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])`. So now use `var reg = /^(?=.*[0-9])([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/;`

Answer (score 0):

Just check the each splitted parts with this regex.

```
reg = /^[a-z\d]*(?:[a-z]\d|\d[a-z])[a-z\d]*$/i;
```

And also note that `^[a-z0-9]+$` would also the words which has only alphabets or digits.